# Oracle PLSQL case statement

Tags: plsql

Why won't this CASE statement work in pl/sql?  I'm trying to assign multiple values in one go.  Is there a faster way to assign multiple values based on the below?  Thanks.

```
DECLARE 
x number := 5;
a CHAR;
b CHAR;
c CHAR;

BEGIN 

CASE 
  WHEN x = 5 THEN a :='rx' AND b := 'rt' AND c :='ry';
  WHEN ...
  WHEN ...

END



END;
```

Comment: Statements are separated with semicolons in PL/SQL, not with `AND`. You did that when declaring variables, what's different in the `THEN` block?

Comment: Also your `case` statement needs to end with `end case;` And a `char` without a size defaults to `char(1)`, which will be too small for your values. And the standard short text string datatype is `varchar2` - it's best not to use `char` ever. (And your caps lock is on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE 
x NUMBER := 5;
a VARCHAR2(2);
b VARCHAR2(2);
c VARCHAR2(2);

BEGIN 
    IF(x = 5)
    THEN
        a :='rx';
        b := 'rt';
        c :='ry';
    END IF;
END;
```

You should use case keyword inside sql queries, but in this scenario when you want to set varaibels you need to use [If Then Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS386).